# Change of variables in multi-variable calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

About the last equality, I know it is change of variables.

Let $\xi=x+t,\eta=-x+t$, but I don't know how to get the integration domain?

I have been thinking for an hour and I can't get the result?

Can anyone help me about this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the equations in $\xi\eta$-plane:

$$t=\frac{\xi+\eta}{2}, x=\frac{\xi-\eta}{2}$$

The range will be then

$$0\leq \xi-\eta\leq2, 0\leq\xi+\eta\leq 2$$

which is the enclosed region

[image]